# how to use Dataset with aggregate function in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, dataset

I have to find max value of one table using dataset.
I have written code for that as follows :

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select max(FlightBookingID) from dbo.FlightBookingDetails", FlyCon);
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds != null)
    {
      Session["FBookingID"] = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FlightBookingID"]);
    }
```

But its geting error in

```
Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FlightBookingID"]);
```

What changes should i do in above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)?

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select max(FlightBookingID) from dbo.FlightBookingDetails", FlyCon))
{
    var result = comm.ExecuteScalar();
    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(result))
        Session["FBookingID"] = result;
}
```

[`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) is very complex class, and you shouldn't create it just to get one value from the database.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. I'd Just add the fact that this may return an annoying DBNull.Value instead of null when no data exist. In this case it is better, I think, to convert DBNull to null before using it on the app.

Comment: yeah but he wrote on the question : "I have to find max value of one table using dataset." ....

Comment: @2GDev He simply creates dataset to get first value of the first row of the first table! It is completely wrong practice, and I didn't find anything in his code what will cause some problems with adding my code.

Comment: You should be wrapping the instantiation of `SqlCommand` in a `using` statement.

Comment: @Oded Thanks. In post there is no such code, and I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item["FlightBookingID"].toString();
```

You are getting String directly here

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Session["FBookingID"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FlightBookingID"].ToString();
```

Comment: do you have given .ToString() at end?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Alias on your query :

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select max(FlightBookingID) as FlightBookingID from dbo.FlightBookingDetails", FlyCon)
```

and so you can acces the column by name. Otherwise you can access it by column index :

```
Session["FBookingID"] = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```